# Get storage metadata in Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

is it possible to get custom storage metadata in Cloud Functions for Firebase?
for example in android code:

```
 StorageMetadata metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder().setContentType("image/jpg")
                        .setCustomMetadata("latitude",String.valueOf(image.latitude))
                        .setCustomMetadata("longitude",String.valueOf(image.longitude))
                        .setCustomMetadata("deviceID",image.deviceID)
                        .setCustomMetadata("userID",image.userID)
                        .setCustomMetadata("deviceFilePath",image.filename)
                        .setCustomMetadata("timestamp",String.valueOf(image.timestamp))
                        .setCustomMetadata("caption",image.caption)
                        .setCustomMetadata("location",image.location)
                        .setCustomMetadata("imageID",key)
                        .build();
```

i want to retrieved the custom metadata value in cloud function

Answer (score 2):

Use this.

```
}).then(() => {
    return file.getMetadata();
}).then((meta) => {
    console.log(meta[0]);
    value1 = meta[0]["metadata"]["key1"];
    value2 = meta[0]["metadata"]["key2"];
```

Comment: This is actually the way to go. Firebase documentation is really bad in this regard but in the SDK Docs, I could at least find an [explanation](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/global.html#GetFileMetadataResponse) why to access `meta[0]`: `meta[0]` is `The File metadata.` whereas `meta[1]` is `The full API response.` Both are objects and you still somehow need to know you need to access `meta[0]["metadata"]` to get the object that contains your custom metadata.

Answer (score 1):

You can get custom metadata in cloud functions as shown below using event.data.metadata.

If you want to see complete example, here is the link http://www.zoftino.com/android-firebase-cloud-functions-cloud-storage-trigger-example

```
exports.metadata = functions.storage.object().onChange(event => {

  //metada
  const fileInfo = event.data;

 //custom metadata
  const customMetadata = fileInfo.metadata;

   //get each custom metadata value using its key like.. 
  const customMetadataDeviceID = customMetadata['deviceID'];

.......
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use the [Google Cloud Storage Node SDK](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-node#cloud-storage-ga) to work with files in your storage bucket.  Use it to get a [File](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/storage/1.1.0/storage/file) object that points to the file of interest.  Then call its [getMetadata()](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/storage/1.1.0/storage/file?method=getMetadata) method to get the metadata.

Comment: do you have any example how to do that?

Comment: Nothing handy, but the API docs are pretty straightforward, so you should be able to experiment with it.